# get value in javascript from select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript function to get the id from a particular `<select></select>`.

```
<select name="no" id="dropdownlist" class="defaultvalue" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

But the problem is I have 8 `<select></select>` for dropwdown and i want to get the value of these in the javascript like:

```
var list = document.getElementById('dropdownlist');
```

But this is only possible through using `getElementByClass` but this is not working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do your different drop down lists have the same `id`? This is not allowed, which may be why things are not working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getElementByClass`, it's `getElementsByClassName`, but you might as well use `querySelectorAll`, which has better support

```
var list  = [];

var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.defaultvalue');

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    list.push( elems[i].value );
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryXpD/)

in jQuery you can do

```
var list = $.map($('.defaultvalue'), function(el) { return el.value});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryXpD/1/)

And ID's are unique, they can not be used for more than one element in the same document

Answer (score 4):

Due you tagged your question with jquery I suggest you using it:

```
$('#dropdownlist').val();
```

UPDATE: But if you have 8 selects - just use same class for them and you can use next code:

```
$('.className').each(function(i,el){
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: This works assuming the OP doesn't have multiple dropdown lists all with the same id and want to get all the various values.  If that's the case, then they need to fix their HTML and use `.each()` to iterate through each one.

Comment: @jfriend00 sure. but for now OP didn't confirm that he has lots of lists with the same id.

Comment: He claims he has 8, but not with the same ID, but with a class ?

Comment: no i did have 8 with same id. i just removed all the id and now using same class for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with pure javascript with multi select tag, then use below code

**Update**

```
function getAllValue(){
    var allSelectTags  = document.getElementsByClassName("defaultvalue");
    var selVal = [];

    for(var i=0; i<allSelectTags.length; i++){
         var value = allSelectTags[i].options[allSelectTags[i].selectedIndex].value;
         selVal.push(value);
    }
    var result = "";
    for(var j=0; j<selVal.length; j++){
        result += selVal[j] + "<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wpY8f/3/)

Comment: Turns out the OP has 8 select lists and wants to get all the values.

Comment: @jfriend00, Please have a look udpated answer.